# call android activity from jni directly from c++ process without java side

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using Eclipse and developing an Android app which have a Java coding and also jni C++ code.

I'm trying to start an activity of Java directly from the jni without touching the Java side.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: It is possible, basically the same logic as in Java side. You need to create an intent of the activity you want on C++ using JNI. This post is not much complete but it should give you an idea. http://vkswtips.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/android-how-to-call-java-activity-using.html

Comment: I have seen it before but how should I use the contextObj value and launch java activity? tnx for reply(:

Comment: You will use class loader to find your activity class (findClass method of class loader). Then, you will construct an intent object, finally you will launch that intent using context object (startActivity method of context).

Comment: sorry I'm rude but can you be more specific and write a simple code that will describe the things you said? I will appreciate it very much!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ok I found out how to do it finally! it's work!
The only thing you need to change is write your package name and class name in 
`NewStringUTF` for example: `NewStringUTF("org.samples.test.MyClass")`

note: `app` is your `android_app*`

```
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVM* lJavaVM = app->activity->vm;
app->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

jobject lNativeActivity = app->activity->clazz;
jclass intentClass = env->FindClass("android/content/Intent");
jstring actionString =env->NewStringUTF("Package Name. Class Name");
jmethodID newIntent = env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "<init>", "()V");
jobject intent = env->AllocObject(intentClass);
env->CallVoidMethod(intent, newIntent);
jmethodID setAction = env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "setAction","(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;");
env->CallObjectMethod(intent, setAction, actionString);
jclass activityClass = env->FindClass("android/app/Activity");
jmethodID startActivity = env->GetMethodID(activityClass,"startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V");
jobject intentObject = env->NewObject(intentClass,newIntent);
env->CallVoidMethod(intentObject, setAction,actionString);
env->CallVoidMethod(lNativeActivity, startActivity, intentObject);
app->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

you also need to add this code in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".JavaActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="you.package.path.JavaActivity" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: app is the struct variable comes as a parameter to android_main like the following.

void android_main(struct android_app* app)

Comment: I see. Can you please tell me Where can I place the call for that method?

Comment: you can place it any where tou want or you can create an method like void LaunchJava(android_app* app,const char* name){}   and replace NewStringUTF with jstring actionString =env->NewStringUTF(name); now you can call the method from any where.

Comment: @RickRoydAban - To get a handle to app, you need to implement your class using NativeActivity.  See this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Comment: Is the following line necessary:
jobject intent = env->AllocObject(intentClass);

Could you not just use intentObject anywhere intent is used ?

Comment: Please let me know if this solution can be used in GoogleTest TEST macro. Thanks.

Comment: This answer was extremely useful.