# Android JNI and NewGlobalRef

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm working with SDL and I've almost sorted out all the issues that I am having.

I am making a jni call to init the framework, then creating a global reference from that because that's the best way that I can think of for the moment.

Most of my JNI functions use the instance variables except for one to read files.
This is how I am setting up the globalref.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL SDL_Android_Init(JNIEnv* mEnv, jobject instance)
{
    Android_JNI_SetupThread();
    mInstance = instance;

    jclass clazz = (*mEnv)->GetObjectClass(mEnv, instance);
    mActivityClass = (jclass)((*mEnv)->NewGlobalRef(mEnv, clazz));
.....
}
```

I only use this mActivityClass global reference twice in this code to read do some functions that can be called at anytime.

The main question, specifically for android JNI. If I hold on to that globalref, since android controls it's application's lifecycle that ref will cause my app to "resume" even though i am attempting to quit.

If I try to clear that globalref with something like `DeleteLocalRef`, the app still seems to want to resume instead of quitting. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Another question, is it possible to create a non static JNI function that get's called from the c side of the code world, so that I can get an instance jobject and use that to get a hold of the class instance?

For example typically you write a function in java:

```
public native void do_c_work();
```

on the c side:

```
void Java_com_test_java_do_c_work(JNIEnv* env, jobject inst)
{
  ...use the instance do your work
}
```

What if some functions get called on the c side, that I would like to get an instance from java to do something with.

c function:

```
public int get_number();
```

I am a little stuck here, I don't want to instantiate a new java object at this point, mainly because [i saw this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326302/call-android-activity-from-jni-directly-from-c-process-without-java-side) and it seems like overkill.

There must be a way to overcome this obstacle, either by being able to call into java from c without using static or creating a new activity, there's one already there or freeing the globalref but that doesn't seem to be working out so well for me at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1. JNI global references do not force your app to stay open.  The garbage collector is aware of them, but the app framework that controls the lifecycle is not.  There are plenty of global references created by the app framework itself.  (Apps are not "garbage collected".)
2. If you want to delete a global reference, use `DeleteGlobalRef`, not `DeleteLocalRef`.
3. If you want to invoke non-static Java-language methods from C, pass the Object to native code, and [invoke a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4256) on it.  Create a global reference for the jobject if you're going to be using it after the native method returns to the VM.  (I feel like maybe I'm not understanding this part of the question.)

See also [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) and the [JNI spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

Answer (score -1):

What's the purpose of holding a `GlobalRef` to a `jclass`? If it's only so you can get `methodIDs`, get them now in this code, and store them. They are only ints, not object references, so you don't have to `GlobalRef` anything.

Comment: I do get jobjects with this ref, I need to get the application context which is a jobject as well as jmethodID, ex: jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, mActivityClass, "getContext", "()Landroid/content/Context;"); | jobject context = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, mActivityClass, mid);