# how to prevent an Android App root detection failed in a frida code 'antiroot'

Tags: android, mobile, frida

On rooted device(by Magisk), my Android app failed root detection when using the below frida code. The app contains root detection module and obfuscation.
Anything I can do to prevent bypass? Is [Protect the app from bypassing the root detection (Frida Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465880/protect-the-app-from-bypassing-the-root-detection-frida-server) also would work for the case?
Thanks in advance.

```
Java.perform(function() {
    var RootPackages = ["com.topjohnwu.magisk"
    ];
    var RootBinaries = ["su", "busybox", "magisk"];
    var RootProperties = {
        "ro.build.selinux": "1",
        "ro.debuggable": "0",
        "service.adb.root": "0",
        "ro.secure": "1"
    };
    var RootPropertiesKeys = [];

    for (var k in RootProperties) RootPropertiesKeys.push(k);

    var NativeFile = Java.use('java.io.File');
    var ProcessBuilder = Java.use('java.lang.ProcessBuilder');
    var useProcessManager = false;

    NativeFile.exists.implementation = function() {
        var name = NativeFile.getName.call(this);
        var shouldFakeReturn = (RootBinaries.indexOf(name) > -1);
        if (shouldFakeReturn) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return this.exists.call(this);
        }
    };

    ProcessBuilder.start.implementation = function() {
        var cmd = this.command.call(this);
        var shouldModifyCommand = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < cmd.size(); i = i + 1) {
            var tmp_cmd = cmd.get(i).toString();
            if (tmp_cmd.indexOf("getprop") != -1 || tmp_cmd.indexOf("mount") != -1 || tmp_cmd.indexOf("build.prop") != -1 || tmp_cmd.indexOf("id") != -1) {
                shouldModifyCommand = true;
            }
        }
        if (shouldModifyCommand) {
            this.command.call(this, ["grep"]);
            return this.start.call(this);
        }
        if (cmd.indexOf("su") != -1) {
            this.command.call(this, ["SOMEFAKECMD"]);
            return this.start.call(this);
        }
        return this.start.call(this);
    };

    if (useProcessManager) {
        var ProcManExec = ProcessManager.exec.overload('[Ljava.lang.String;', '[Ljava.lang.String;', 'java.io.File', 'boolean');
    
        ProcManExec.implementation = function(cmd, env, workdir, redirectstderr) {
            var fake_cmd = cmd;
            for (var i = 0; i < cmd.length; i = i + 1) {
                var tmp_cmd = cmd[i];
                if (tmp_cmd.indexOf("getprop") != -1 || tmp_cmd == "mount" || tmp_cmd.indexOf("build.prop") != -1 || tmp_cmd == "id") {
                    var fake_cmd = ["grep"];
                }
                if (tmp_cmd == "su") {
                    var fake_cmd = ["SOMEFAKECMD"];
                }
            }
            return ProcManExec.call(this, fake_cmd, env, workdir, redirectstderr);
        };
    }
});
```

(the code originally from https://codeshare.frida.re/@dzonerzy/fridantiroot/ , removed unnecessary parts)

Comment: Without knowing the app and the root detection code it used it is unknown which anti-root code may work. Decompile the app, check the code where the root detection is located. If you have the relevant methods you may directly hook them using frida and return the expected result for a non-rooted device.